# Assign global struct variable outside main And Inside main

Tags: c, struct, program-entry-point

**the problem is when I separated the code into the different function and this happens**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//------Options -- change only true / false to trigger the function
bool hard_trace = false;
bool trace = true;
/*-------------------*/

//---------Defines----------
#define MAXSIZE 100 // maximum size of the characters in txt file to be buffed
/*----------------------*/

//---------Structs-----------
struct Matrix
{
    char *A[10];
    int depth;
};
/*--------------------------*/
//-----Variable----------
//-- global
char *B[3];
//- struct
struct Matrix matrixs ; // create new global struct
//-
//--
/*-----------------------*/

int convertCharToNumber(char target[1])
{
    int numbered = target[0] - 48;
    return numbered;
}

int generateDataFromFile(){
    //-- temped
    int currentLine = 1;
    int currentRow = 0;
    //-----------------
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAXSIZE];

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error reading from file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAXSIZE, fp) != NULL)
    {
        if(hard_trace){ // if it was enabled
            printf("current line : %d and length : %d\n", currentLine, strlen(line));
        }
        if (line[strlen(line) - 1] == '\n') // cutout the \n to make the txt easy to use
        {
            line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
        }
        //appileToStruct(line,currentRow);
        matrixs.A[currentRow] = line;
        //if(trace) printf("%s\n", line);
        currentLine++; currentRow++;
    }
    if(trace) printf("Total line receive from txt file : %d\n" , currentLine-1); //if it was enabled
    fclose(fp);

    // ----------- assign the var
    matrixs.depth = currentLine - 1;
    //----------------------------

    //return 1;
}

void main(){
    generateDataFromFile();
    printf("Total : %d TXT : [%s]", strlen(matrixs.A[0]), matrixs.A[0]);
}
```

**and the output here**

Total line recieve from txt file : 3

Total : 10 TXT : []

.

**But it's fine when i directly put the code in the main like this**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//------Options -- change only true / false to trigger the function
bool hard_trace = false;
bool trace = true;
/*-------------------*/

//---------Defines----------
#define MAXSIZE 100 // maximum size of the characters in txt file to be buffed
/*----------------------*/

//---------Structs-----------
struct Matrix
{
    char *A[10];
    int depth;
};
/*--------------------------*/
//-----Variable----------
//-- global
char *B[3];
//- struct
struct Matrix matrixs; // create new global struct
//-
//--
/*-----------------------*/

int convertCharToNumber(char target[1])
{
    int numbered = target[0] - 48;
    return numbered;
}

int main()
{
    //-- temped
    int currentLine = 1;
    int currentRow = 0;
    //-----------------
    FILE *fp;
    char line[MAXSIZE];

    fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", "Error reading from file");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAXSIZE, fp) != NULL)
    {
        if (hard_trace)
        { // if it was enabled
            printf("current line : %d and length : %d\n", currentLine, strlen(line));
        }
        if (line[strlen(line) - 1] == '\n') // cutout the \n to make the txt easy to use
        {
            line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
        }
        //appileToStruct(line,currentRow);
        matrixs.A[currentRow] = line;
        //if(trace) printf("%s\n", line);
        currentLine++;
        currentRow++;
    }
    if (trace)
        printf("Total line recieve from txt file : %d\n", currentLine - 1); //if it was enabled
    fclose(fp);

    // ----------- assign the var
    matrixs.depth = currentLine - 1;
    //----------------------------

    printf("Total : %d TXT : [%s]", strlen(matrixs.A[0]), matrixs.A[0]);
}
```

**OUTPUT**

Total line receive from txt file : 3

Total : 10 TXT : [0000111100]

**Can you guy explain to me why that the first code is not working i mean why the %s in printf doesn't show the output for me and how can i get the first code to be work**

Comment: That's why: `matrixs.A[currentRow] = line;`. `line` is local to the function in the first case. This statement assigned pointer, it doesn't copy the string, so when everything is in `main()` `line` is well defined in that scope while in the first case `line` is local array which belongs to `generateDataFromFile()`

Comment: @AlexLop. And how can I get the above code to work, I really have no idea to work on it, I don't want to put all my function directly in the main function can you please guide me. because I also don't have 100% understanding of pointer things

Comment: I'll update my answer with proposed fix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do this:

```
matrixs.A[currentRow] = line;
```

You're assigning the address of the local array `line` to an element of `matrixs.A`.  In the case of the second program, it prints a valid value because `line` in still in scope.  But in the first program `line` is out of scope so `matrixs.A[0]` points to invalid memory.  Dereferencing this pointer invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, in the second program, you may notice that every element of `matrixs.A` contains the last value you read.  That is again because you're storing the address of `line` in each one.

You should instead make a *copy* of the string you read and save a pointer to the new string.  That way 1) you're not storing the address of a local variable, and 2) you don't store the same address in every element of `matrixs.A`.

```
matrixs.A[currentRow] = strdup(line);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's why: `matrixs.A[currentRow] = line;`.

`line` is local to the function in the first case. This statement assigned pointer, it doesn't copy the strings (**you should use `strncpy` instead and don't forget to allocate the required memory space by `malloc`**), so when everything is in the `main()`, `line` is well defined in that scope so `matrixs.A[0]` is a pointer to the existing `line` while in the first case line is local array which belongs to generateDataFromFile().

When you try to print `matrixs.A[0]` from `main()` (in the first case), you invoke *undefined behavior* because you are performing *stack violation* and trying to access some address on the stack which may contain whatever you want at that point of the flow execution.

Proposed fix:

```
// instead of matrixs.A[currentRow] = line
size_t lineSize = strlen(line)+1;
matrixs.A[currentRow] = malloc(lineSize);
strncpy(matrixs.A[currentRow], line, lineSize);
```

And don't forget to `free()` the allocated memory at the end.

Comment: Thank you Alex, this is the right answer also. but I don't know how to mark the green tick at the multiple answers i am really new here

Comment: @learnerez It's OK. You can mark only one answer as the *Right Answer*. But you can always "vote up" an answer if you like it ;)

Comment: Oh, Very thank again for the Proposed fix, I tried and it works, and now I think I have to learn on malloc and memory thing, .... and seem like I can't vote because I have less than 15 reputations as the popup shown, ANYWAY THANK YOU AGAIN;D